# Directive for add new contact

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

This is my custom directive,

```
var directiveProvider = angular.module('AppDirective',[]);

directiveProvider.directive('addNewContact', function() {

var custom_template = '<div id="" class="Edit-box"><h4>Contact</h4><div class="form-group">' +
            '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">First Name </label><div class="col-sm-4">' +
            '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter ..." class="form-control"></div>' +
            '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Last Name</label><div class="col-sm-4">'+
            '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter ..." class="form-control"></div></div>' +
            '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Email</label>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-4">' +
            '<input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" id="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-control"></div>' +
            '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Telephone</label><div class="col-sm-4">' +
            '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter ..." class="form-control"></div></div></div>';

return {

    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: custom_template,
    scope: {
      firstName: '='
    },
    link: function ($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        console.debug($scope);
    }
};
});
```

and in html I have

```
<div id="addContact" add-new-contact ></div>
    <div ng-click="addNewContactHTML()">
      <a>Add New Contact</a>
    </div>
```

and in my controller I have

```
$scope.addNewContactHTML = function(){
    var compiledeHTML = $compile("<div add-New-Contact ></div>")($scope);
    $("#addContact").append(compiledeHTML);
};
```

so that on button click I, a new empty template is added and details can be input. I am not sure, how to create the directive and how I can access the model in controller so that I can save the data from controller.

Comment: Please guide me, if my approach is wrong.

Comment: i think this, you should learn about more, here the example                              https://plnkr.co/edit/Gi2GFqQmXINqOhiCcGmI?p=preview

Comment: @Chathura, thank for the prompt reply, I think you got me wrong, with ref to your example, when I click on Add new contact, the fname, lname and other fields should replicate so the user can enter another name.

Comment: ah got it i update it..

Comment: yes, thank you... i got it so far..but my problem is how can I get the data from the directive in the controller. Say, if I have save action in my controller.

http://plnkr.co/edit/gtj48xYMpzHIsgABZFdJ?p=info

Comment: in that case u have, define save button in side the directive --see my last update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111420/discussion-between-jayaraj-ps-and-chathura-hettiarachchi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by use an array,
Here the angular Part

```
 var app = angular.module('AppDirective',[]);

app.directive('addNewContact', function() {



return {
    scope:{
      obj:'='
    },
    templateUrl: 'tempbody.html',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {




    }
};
});

app.controller('myController',['$scope','$compile',function($scope,$compile){


  $scope.details=[{fname:'',lname:'',mail:'',telephone:''}];

    $scope.addNewContactHTML = function(){
      $scope.details.push({fname:'',lname:'',mail:'',telephone:''}); 
  }



}]);
```

Here HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cc.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="AppDirective">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div id="addContact">
      <div  add-new-contact="detail" ng-repeat="detail in details"></div>
    </div>

     <div ng-click="addNewContactHTML()">
        <a>Add New Contact</a>
      </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tempbody.html">
    <div class="Edit-box">
      <h4>Contact</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Fname</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ..." class="form-control" ng-modal="obj.fname">
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Lname</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ..." class="form-control" ng-modal="obj.lname">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3" ng-modal="obj.mail">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" id="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3" ng-modal="obj.telephone">Telephone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ..." class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```